# Binary Search Tree Insert Not Functioning Correctly in C (possibly an ignorant error)

Tags: c, data-structures, binary-tree

I'm trying to make a BST tree structure in C but I'm having some difficulty getting my insert function working. After reading some examples, I've discovered that the best way to go about it is by passing in a pointer to the root of the tree and then recursively inserting on that node until an empty Node (NULL) is found. However, I'm trying to pass in an entire Tree structure (just so everything is neatly encapsulated) and I thought I came up with the following solution:

```
void insert(struct Node* temp, char *s){

if (temp  == NULL) {
  struct Node *newNode = make_node();
  newNode-> data = strdup(s);
  temp = newNode;
  return;


}
 if (strcmp(s,temp->data) > 0) {
  temp = temp->left;
  insert(temp, s);
  }
 if (strcmp(s,temp->data) < 0) {
   temp = temp->right;
   insert(temp, s);
  }

 }
//--------------------------------------------------------------                                      
 void insert_tree(struct BSP * tree, char *s) {

    struct Node *temp = tree->root;
    insert(temp, s);

 }
//-------------------------------------------------------------
```

When I insert into the Tree, I call insert_tree(), but then I use insert() as a way to just recursively insert on a node that should point to the root of the tree.
P.S The structure of the BSP and Nodes are:

```
typedef struct Node {
   struct Node * left;
   struct Node * right;
   char * data;

 } node;

 typedef struct BSP {
  struct Node * root;
  int size;
}
```

Can anyone help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What is actually going wrong?

Comment: Whats an ignorant error? My errors tend to be very literate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First answer is right, but you always can use pointer to pointer, something like this.

```
typedef struct Node
{
    Node()
    {
        left = NULL;
        right = NULL;
        data = NULL;
    }

    struct Node* left;
    struct Node* right;
    char* data;
} node;

typedef struct BSP
{
    BSP()
    {
        root = NULL;
        size = 0;
    }

    struct Node* root;
    int size;
} bsp;

void insert(struct Node** temp, char* s)
{
    Node* node = *temp;

    if (node == NULL)
    {
        struct Node* newNode = new Node();
        newNode->data = strdup(s);
        (*temp) = newNode;
        return;
    }

    if (strcmp(s, node->data) > 0)
    {
        insert(&node->left, s);
    }

    if (strcmp(s, node->data) < 0)
    {
        insert(&node->right, s);
    }
}

void insert_tree(struct BSP* tree, char* s)
{
    insert(&tree->root, s);
    tree->size++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this response. Not only did it help me get the code working, but now I feel like I finally understand why using pointers to pointers can be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are throwing away the new node.  In C function arguments are pass by value which means that changing temp in the insert function does not change it in the caller.

Insert should return the newly created node and you need to do something with it in the caller.